# json jquery issue

Tags: php, jquery, json

i am using this to get informations from ajax jquery in json formate but it give me error
like this 0 =[object object]

```
$.getJSON("ajax_files/getSingleRow.php?id="+id+"&type="+type, function(json){ 
                 $.each(json, function(key, val) {
                    //$("#"+key).val(val);
                    alert(key+'='+val);
                 });
                 });
```

here is my josn string

```
[{"id":"1","ref":"RH-R-1","name":"","description_demo":"this is desc test"}]
```

---

Thanks all...here is how my json develops

```
  while($rw = $oAppl->row($res))
{
 $return[]=array('id'=>$rw['id'],
                'ref'=>$rw['ref'],
                'name'=>$rw['name'],
                'description_demo'=>$rw['description_demo']);
}

    header('Content-type: application/json');
   echo json_encode($return);
```

Comment: Why do you think that is an error?

Comment: Your json is an Array with one element that is an object.

Comment: Do `alert(json)` to see the data you received??

Comment: @asifsid88 The `alert()` function is awful for debugging and displaying information, as they've just discovered, because it doesn't show the properties of objects.

Answer (score 2):

The JSON text consists of an array containing an object.

When you loop over it, you get the first key of the array (`0`) and then the string serialisation of the object (`[Object object]`). Then it stops because there is only one entry in the array.

This is **not an error**. It is expected behaviour given the data you are inputting.

Possibly you want to loop over the object instead, in which case:

```
var ob = json[0];
$.each(ob, function(key, val) {
```

Answer (score 0):

That isn't an error, strictly, it's an object. It might contain an error, who knows. But the thing itself is a thing waiting to be accessed (i.e., the value of `val`) and there's nothing inherently erroneous with it.

Try accessing the members, output the `id`, `name`, etc, instead of just dumping the thing in an alert.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.getJSON("ajax_files/getSingleRow.php?id=" + id + "&type=" + type, function (json) {
    $.each(json, function (key, val) {

        // This will only give you the 'ref' value
        alert(key + '=' + val.ref);

        // To loop through all the values
        $.each(val, function (key2, data) {
            alert(key2 + ": " + data);
        });
    });
});
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/YhuhZ/)

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON string is wrapped inside an array. `[ {} ]` Leave the  "`[`" and "`]`" out.

Answer (score 0):

Read the propery value of your JSON collection item.

```
 $.each(json, function(key, item) {
     alert(key+'='+item.id);
     alert(key+'='+item.ref);
     alert(key+'='+item.description_demo);
 });
```

This should work fine assuming you have no other script errors in your page.

Working sample : http://jsfiddle.net/a4Efx/4/